# Test class are failing because of one Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, class, error

I am allocating a customer community user license whenever a lead is converted into contact and it's working fine. below is my code:

```java
trigger CreateCommunityUser on Contact (After insert) {
        
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Contact co : trigger.new){
            Contact con = [select id,email,firstName,lastname,accountId from Contact where Id =:co.Id];         
            Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
            dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = false;       
            dmo.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail = false;
            dmo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;       
            dmo.optAllOrNone = false; */
    
            // create portal user
            string nick = con.email!=null?con.email.substring(0, con.email.indexOf('@')):'';
            nick += Datetime.now().getTime();
            User newUser1 = new User(alias=con.firstName, email = con.email, emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', firstname = con.firstName, lastname = con.lastname, languagelocalekey = 'en_US',localesidkey = 'en_US',contactId = con.Id,timezonesidkey = 'Asia/Dubai',username = con.email,CommunityNickname = nick,ProfileId ='00e6F000001kZ4C', IsActive = true);
            newUser1.setOptions(dmo); 
            insert newUser1;
        }
    }
}
```

Because of this code, most of my other test classes are failing with these errors:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CreateCommunityUser: execution of AfterInsert
> caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STRING_TOO_LONG, Alias: data value too large: FirstName (max length=8): [Alias]
> Trigger.CreateCommunityUser: line 16, column 1: []
> FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CreateCommunityUser: execution of AfterInsert

Please guide me where am I going wrong.
Thanks already.

Comment: The error spells it out `STRING_TOO_LONG, Alias: data value too large: FirstName (max length=8)`. There are other issues (query in a loop, you shouldn't need the query at all, not checking if the contact has been converted from a lead, DML inside a loop), but the alias length is the primary issue.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum length of `User.Alias` (8) is significantly shorter than the maximum length of `ContactFirstName` (40). You need to truncate to fit. Often the `String.abbreviate` method is most convenient for this purpose, but for `Alias` you should probably prefer `substring`.

Your code should look something like:

```
String alias = con.firstName;
if (alias.length() > 8)
    alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
insert new User(Alias = alias, ...);
```